# How can I make the options-collection to show the items of a string list?

Tags: java, string, jsp, stripes

If I want to show the id's of items of some list, I write:

```
<stripes:options-collection collection="${itemsList}" value="id"/>
```

But if I got a list of strings, how can I show them? What should I put into `value`?

```
<stripes:options-collection collection="${stringsList}" ??????/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple - I shouldn't use any `value`. So, the line in stripes should look as:

```
<stripes:options-collection collection="${stringsList}"/>
```

This way the items of the list will be shown directly.